# How do I do 3d shoe manipulations

Tags: images, 3d

I would like to know how the images below are done:

[image]

[image]

They are based off this image of a shoe:

[image]

If you guys know of any similar tutorials, let me know. Or if you guys are THAT advanced. Id like some instructions!

Comment: They are very complex, very well executed 3D models. You’d need some 3D software with a good render engine (3D Studio Max or similar) and probably about 10 years practice.

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad because, well, there isn't one simple "how-to" tutorial for these different 3D models.

Comment: Besides the fact that is pretty obvious that they are 3D models, the below image has not the necessary information to make the models above, for example, it does not show the sole. Do not assume one thing, you need to learn how to observe a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The first two examples have almost certainly been created using 3d modelling software. Something like Maya, Blender, Cinema 4D, etc.

Although I can't be 100% sure, the second example looks like it might simply be a photograph, with the background removed and replaced with a solid green background - probably using the Pen tool to create a vector mask in Photoshop. It is also possible that it could be a 3d model.

There are some [Blender tutorials here](https://www.youtube.com/user/blendercookie/search?query=shoe) - specifically for modelling shoes, and to texturize them.

Answer (score 0):

Those were almost certainly 3D modeled and rendered. Could be any of the major DCC tools out there: Blender, Maya, 3DS, modo, Cinema 4D, or even could be DCC sculpting tools like mudbox or zbrush.